# pandas,how to get the index after using the func pandas.Series.value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas, count

there is my code
..

```
code_c = data.code.value_counts()
print code_c
ss = code_c.loc[code_c.values == 15]
print ss
```

get:

```
>>>code_c
600644    16
600101    16
600652    15
600256    15
717       15
600282    15
543       15
709       15
          ..
2352       5
2478       5
2379       5
>>>ss
600652    15
600256    15
807       15
600868    15
531       15
795       15
600188    15
          ..
```

I have the trouble getting the list(600652,600256,807,600686,...)
Can you help me?thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index via the `index` attribute.

```
ss.index.tolist()  # to return a list
```

or

```
# to return a pandas series with index values as series values
ss.index.to_series()
```